# Remove a custom options name/value pair

Tags: plugins

I'm writing a plugin of which one aspect is the deletion of a custom option in the Options table. The situation is complicated by the fact that the custom option is an array, not just a variable/value. The data is stored in an options field with the name:

**swcs_postpage_id**

My test data currently contains two items in the array:

**a:2:{i:0;s:2:"10";i:1;s:3:"605";}**

These were added by the user selecting a number of options in a form in the main plugin file. In my test data the two values are '10' and '605'.

I am not sure how to go about removing an item from the array. E.g. if the user selects '605' to delete, how do I remove that name/value from the array, leaving all the others?

I have read up on delete_option and update_option but neither are making an awful lot of sense to me at the moment!

**UPDATE** -based on MMK's help below, here's the code:

```
$toremove = 605 // I actually use a var like so $toremove = $_REQUEST['somevar']; I'm just using 605 as an example
$selectid = get_option('swcs_postpage_id');
$key = array_search ($toremove, $selectid);
unset($selectid[$key]);
update_option(swcs_postpage_id, $selectid);
```

Comment: Your option `swcs_postpage_id`  contains an array. If your user selects `605` then simply do a search like so and unset your value `unset( key( $your_var_containing_deletion_key ) - 1 );` More info on key: http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php" and on unset: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: Thanks MMK (again) - I'm just bout to edited my post to reflect your answer.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question which is more appropriate than adding it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

based on MMK's help below, here's the code:

```
$toremove = 605 // I actually use a var like so $toremove = $_REQUEST['somevar']; I'm just using 605 as an example
$selectid = get_option('swcs_postpage_id');
$key = array_search ($toremove, $selectid);
unset($selectid[$key]);
update_option(swcs_postpage_id, $selectid);
```